# Google Chrome incomplete sync history

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using google chrome portable on multiple computers (and sometimes multiple portable installations on the same computers) which I have them all signed in and synced to the same account. While everything thing else seem to work just as expected, the history records doesn't seem to be fully synced between each installation.

There are some records that appear across all installations (mostly records from android chrome) and some that only appear on the installation that was used to browse/created that record and stored in the local DB.

Am I missing something here or did Google screwed up on the simple task of syncing 2 columns (timestamp-url) of data? Can I still somehow have the branches merged manually if google won't do it for me?

Comment: I have the same experience since forever... pretty frustrating not to find the stuff again somewhere else... I started bookmarking everything I could ever need again as a HACKFIX...